# Select Text in DIV with specific range using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to select the text inside `<div>` with a specific range ex.

```
<div>This is a sample text.</div>
selectText(3, 12);
```

it will select text from s to m(s is a sam) inside div and the user can copy the text by pressing <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd>

Comment: Can you share some code that you tried? Also, jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: What does ```selectText(3, 12);``` say in your code??

Comment: Unfortunately selecting text programatically is possible with editable elements only for example input or textarea. It won't work with div

Comment: https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/qBdaxwe

Answer (score 3):

```js
let element = document.querySelector('div');

selectText(element, 20, 35);


function selectText(node, start, end) {
  let text = node.childNodes[0];
  let range = new Range();
  let selection = document.getSelection();
  range.setStart(text, start);
  range.setEnd(text, end);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<div>Text not to select. Text to select. Text not to select.</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a sample text.

slice(3, 12);